# Add-remove class dynamically

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div class='m2Act' id='edu'>Edu</div>
<div class='m2Pass' id='ref.php'>Ref</div>
<div class='m2Pass' id='con.php'>Con</div>
<div style='clear:both'></div>
```

css

```
.m2Act, .m2Pass{
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.m2Act{
 background:yellow;   
}
.m2Pass{
    background:red
}
```

js

```
$('.m2Pass').hover(function(){
    $('.m2Act').removeClass().addClass('m2Pass');
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('m2Act');
})
```

All this works, but when the cursor is away - I need to have a previous state of each div. This doesn't happen. divs remains in the new, hovered state. I already tried with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` without success.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bonaca/5gCFv/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should :

- Use the second argument of `hover()` for hover out
- Keep a trace of your initial active item

Updated code :

```
<div class='m2Act initial' id='edu'>Edu</div>
<div class='m2Pass' id='ref.php'>Ref</div>
<div class='m2Pass' id='con.php'>Con</div>
```

```
$('.m2Pass').hover(
    function(){
        $('.m2Act').removeClass('m2Act').addClass('m2Pass');
        $(this).removeClass('m2Pass').addClass('m2Act');
    },
    function(){
        $('.m2Act').removeClass('m2Act').addClass('m2Pass');
        $('.initial').removeClass('m2Pass').addClass('m2Act');
    }
);
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/5gCFv/3/)

**EDIT :**
As mentioned by [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004893/simon) in comments, you can use `toggleClass()` instead of `removeClass()` and `addClass()`, to simplify your code :

```
$('.m2Pass').hover(
    function(){ $('.m2Act').add(this).toggleClass('m2Act m2Pass'); },
    function(){ $('.m2Act, .initial').toggleClass('m2Act m2Pass'); }
);
```

Comment: Btw: why not use `.toggleClass()`?

Comment: `toggleClass()` isn't really useful here. But I would have simplified the use of `.m2Act` and `.m2Pass` by a simple `.m2`, `.m2.active` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/5gCFv/4/))

Comment: Why no useful? You could easily write for example: `$('.m2Act').add(this).toggleClass('m2Act m2Pass');`

Comment: Nice ! I never used jQuery's `add()` function. Indeed, it **is** useful (I'll edit my post to include your proposition)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.m2Pass').hover(function(){
    $('.m2Act').removeClass().addClass('m2Pass');
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('m2Act');
},function(){

 // revert the properties in this function

}
)
```